# Knowing specifically which FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I get the SQLite error message "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed". That's the complete error information (besides a part of the SQL query) and it's not helpful. (In fact it's just as good (or bad) as Oracle error messages.) I need to know the name of the constraint to investigate the issue in my program. Unfortunately there's no web support platform to discuss this with an SQLite community. Does somebody know how to get more information about the error out of that SQLite library?

I'm specifically using the System.Data.SQLite library for .NET but the error message comes directly from the core and there are no additional exception properties that could help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Due to the way in which deferred FK constraints are implemented in SQLite, this information is not available when the error is raised.

You could reimplement the FK checks as triggers.
Alternatively, log the values in the failed command, and look up the data by hand.

Comment: In the case of a UNIQUE constraint failing, I get an error message with the offending table name and column name. I guess a FOREIGN KEY is a little more complicated so it doesn't display that info.

Comment: This would be the single best thing to add to SQLITE is some means of narrowing down the failed FK constraint in the error message. It doesn't have to be fancy.

Comment: @CL. I have been looking into this as well, is there anything specifically in the documentation or the code that leads you to believe this or is it just a guess? Not trying to suggest you're wrong, I am just trying to be optimistic that this can be done. :)

Comment: @CaptainMan Deferrable constraints are checked immediately, but when they fail, an error counter is incremented. When the target table is changed and the new row fixes an error, the counter is decremented. When the counter is still set at the commit, the error is raised. At that time, the only information available is the counter.

Comment: Well, then they need something smarter than a simple counter.

Comment: The sqlite-users@sqlite.org mailing list archive has a long thread dating back to 2015 discussing this very issue: [How hard is it to add the constraint name to the 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' message?](https://sqlite-users.sqlite.narkive.com/dbLQTqwB/sqlite-how-hard-is-it-to-add-the-constraint-name-to-the-foreign-key-constraint-failed-message)

Answer (score 0):

In a Django project, here below is what I did to replace `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` with (for example) `DETAIL: Key (base_id)=(1a389dc3-5bc1-4132-8a4a-c8200533503a) is not present in table "backend_base"` ...

The solution is Django specific since it's based on Django ORM's methods; `obj` is supposed to be the Model instance which caused the exception upon model.save()

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def explain_integrity_errors(obj):
    """
    Replace 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' error message provided by sqlite
    with something useful (i.e. the exception thrown by PostgreSQL):
    'DETAIL: Key (base_id)=(1a389dc3-5bc1-4132-8a4a-c8200533503a) is not present in table "backend_base"'
    """
    error_msg = ''
    errors = []

    # Scan all FKs
    relation_fields = [f for f in obj._meta.concrete_fields if f.is_relation]
    for field in relation_fields:
        try:
            # try to access the related target
            fk_target = getattr(obj, field.name)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
            # Log offending FK
            fk_field = field.name + '_id'
            fk_value = getattr(obj, fk_field)
            fk_table = field.related_model._meta.db_table
            errors.append('Key (%s)=(%s) is not present in table "%s"' % (
                fk_field,
                str(fk_value),
                fk_table
            ))

    if len(errors):
        error_msg = ' DETAIL: ' + "; ".join(errors)
    return error_msg
```

Comment: Interesting, but what does it do and how is it used (what's the `obj` parameter)? I've no experience with database access in Python.

Comment: Sorry @ygoe, the solution I shared is very Django specific, and I forgot to mention it. I'll update my answer to clarify this