# EF core 6.0 + SQLite foreign key constraint, meaningful error description

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to cover a large project, with complex database schema, with extensive amount of integration tests. For integration tests, I'm using SQLite database. Each time when foreign key constraint is violated, I get an error:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Stack: `EntityFramework core 6.0, SQLite v 6.0`

Connection string:
`Data Source=:memory:;foreign keys=true`

Without explanation, which foreign key is it hit. In a case when entity is complex, it always takes anomalous amount of time to come up which constraint is it.
Is there any way how to extend exception with information on which foreign key constraint has hit?
Something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint - ItemId failed
```

Comment: I think you can handle DbUpdateException and get the information you want

Comment: @BayramEren When I had a look at `DbUpdateException`'s entry in MSDN, I couldn't find any information about violated foreign keys in its read-only list of entity entries.

Comment: I'm not sure but I've used this for a situation close to this. It's worth trying :)

Comment: @BayramEren, yep from that exception details I see a list of foreign-keys that exists however couldn't find how exactly to match which one has failed.

Comment: I'm going to ask something. Are you pressing into fake data sql lite?

Comment: What do you mean by Fake data sql lite? I'm just populating sql lite data with test data. The exception is valid in that case, however it doesn't specify which foreign key constraint is hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knowing specifically which FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302358/knowing-specifically-which-foreign-key-constraint-failed-in-sqlite)

Comment: Yes, @MarkBenningfield , I saw that answer. However I had a hope that it was improved during last 6 years.

Comment: If you set your foreign key constraints to `DEFERRED` and call `PRAGMA foreign_key_check` prior to a `COMMIT`, then you will get a list of all foreign keys in conflict at that time.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, it would be lovely if you would share some solution using EFCore?

Comment: @Maris Please read carefully this instruction : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key. I had also this problem while deleting and problem solved when i add `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` due to this instructtion : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#cascade-delete-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left to itself, SQLite does not close out a transaction when a commit is attempted with foreign keys
in conflict. At that point, you can use [pragma](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#toc) commands to query the state of foreign keys in
conflict, fix or remove them, then proceed with committing the transaction.

However, wrappers for SQLite usually dispose of a transaction as soon as an error is raised, rendering
that solution untenable. In that case, you have to take control of the transaction the wrapper provides.

We're going to assume that you are aware of how to manage transactions in EFCore (external, cross-context, etc.)
that fit your particular scenario. This example just uses a transaction within a single context.

```cs
using var context = new PersonContext();
using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

try
{
  // set all foreign key enforcement to "DEFERRED"
  context.Database.ExecuteSql("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys=1;");

  // various CRUD operations that may involve foreign key conflicts
  
    // read the foreign key information from the table-valued pragma functions
    // `foreign_key_check` and `foreign_key_list`
  string sql = @"select a.""table"" || '.'|| ""from"" from pragma_foreign_key_check a
                   inner join pragma_foreign_key_list(a.""table"") b on
                   b.id == a.fkid;";
                      
  var conflicts = context.Database
    .SqlQuery<string>(sql)
    .ToList();
        
    // the list will contains strings like "tableName.fkColumn"
    // handle conflicts if the list count > 0
    
    // go ahead and commit the transaction
  transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception)
{
  // TODO: Handle failure
}
```

See:
[defer_foreign_keys](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_defer_foreign_keys)
[foreign_key_check](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_check)
[foreign_key_list](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list)